# How to make radiobutton selected by default change some options in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I cannot make my radio button selected by default hide the the entered words in password entry widget (PasswordEntry), my code is below, I tried many way but failed, i don't know what is wrong, normmaly the if statement is meant to work, i tried while too but it gets worst, the widgets are crashing. How can i make the if statement work as it's supposed to? Thanks in advance for your helps.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox 
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import tkinter.font as TkFont
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import tkinter.font
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk



PasswordAsker=Tk() 

screen_x = int(PasswordAsker.winfo_screenwidth())
screen_y = int(PasswordAsker.winfo_screenheight())

window_x = 492
window_y = 150

posX = (screen_x // 2) - (window_x // 2)
posY = (screen_y // 2) - (window_y // 2)

geo = "{}x{}+{}+{}". format(window_x, window_y, posX, posY)  


PasswordAsker.geometry(geo)
PasswordAsker.config(background="gray8")
PasswordAsker.resizable(0,0)
PasswordAsker.title("Enter the password")
PasswordAsker.config(relief="raised")




def kill():
    PasswordAsker.destroy()

          
PasswordLabel = Label(PasswordAsker, text = 'Enter the password', font=('TkDefaultFont', 9, "bold")) 

PasswordLabel.config(background="gray8")
PasswordLabel.config(foreground="red3")   

PasswordEntry = Entry(PasswordAsker, textvariable = name_var,font=('TkDefaultFont',12,'normal'),width=30,borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", selectbackground="dark red") 

PasswordEntry.config(highlightbackground="gray15")
PasswordEntry.config(foreground="red")
PasswordEntry.config(highlightthickness=3)
PasswordEntry.config(highlightcolor="dark red")
PasswordEntry.config(background="gray15")




OkButton=Button(PasswordAsker,text = 'Okay',command = mainwindow, font=('TkDefaultFont', 9, "bold"),borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", activebackground="dark red", bg="gray15",fg="red3")
CancelBtn=Button(PasswordAsker,text = 'Cancel',command = kill, font=('TkDefaultFont', 9, "bold"),borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", activebackground="dark red", bg="gray15",fg="red3")
visibilityOptn = LabelFrame(PasswordAsker, text="Password visibility", height=60, width=130)

PasswordLabel.place(x=5, y=18)
PasswordEntry.place(x=125, y=10)

OkButton.configure(height=1, width=6)
OkButton.place(x=422, y=12)

CancelBtn.configure(height=1, width=6)
CancelBtn.place(x=422, y=52)

visibilityOptn.configure(font=('TkDefaultFont', 8, "bold"), foreground="red3", background="gray8")
visibilityOptn.place(x=260, y=62)


i = StringVar()

w1 = Radiobutton (visibilityOptn,text="Hide",value=1, variable=i, bg="gray8", fg="red3", activebackground="dark red")

w2 = Radiobutton (visibilityOptn,text="Show",value=2, variable=i, bg="gray8", fg="red3", activebackground="dark red")

w1.pack(side="left")
w2.pack(side="right")


if (i.get() ==1):
    PasswordEntry.config(show="•")

else:
    PasswordEntry.config(show="")

i.set("1")

PasswordAsker.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reason why you aren't using a checkbox? I can give you a solution but its much easier if you want a checkbox.

Comment: You're calling `i.get()` about a millisecond after creating the radiobutton, and you haven't given the radiobutton a default value.

Comment: @TheLizzard i prefer radiobutton, pls give your solution with it

Comment: @BryanOakley how i can do that pls? isn't .set to give default value already? i was thinking that i gave it already but late

Comment: @Shadow Kurgansk what do you want the default option to be? Hidden or shown?

Comment: @TheLizzard i want hidden

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes I would make to your code:

```py
...  

PasswordEntry = Entry(..., show="•") 

...

w1 = Radiobutton(visibilityOptn,text="Hide", value=1, bg="gray8", fg="red3", activebackground="dark red", command=lambda: PasswordEntry.config(show="•"))
w2 = Radiobutton(visibilityOptn,text="Show", value=2, bg="gray8", fg="red3", activebackground="dark red", command=lambda: PasswordEntry.config(show=""))

w1.select()

w1.pack(side="left")
w2.pack(side="right")

PasswordAsker.mainloop()
```

Basically I made the password hidden by default in the constructor of the entry. I also put a command on each radio button changing the state of the entry using a lambda function.

Comment: If you need the documentation for tkinter.Radiobutton http://web.archive.org/web/20201112013840/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm